# 3D mapping Cliff Detection

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using rtabmap in my project with Velodyne VLP-16 sensor so that the ground can be identified by the slam algorithm. As mention [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/289171/how-to-create-a-costmap-layer-to-avoid-downward-stairs/) that if I want to detect the cliff robustly, then it requires 3D mapping since it can provide groundtracking.

In reality, the stair should be 3 meters in front of the robot. However, in my mapping, as you can see the following.

[image]

There is no cliff identified in the map since the lidar didn't san the surface of the stair due to the scanning angle.

To my understanding, the meaning of groudtracking is that the ground will be identified and extend and if the lidar sensor failed to have scan return the cliff will then be identified.

Did I misunderstand anything or misconfig anything, if so please do correct me. Thanks.

Best regards,
Jack Lu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384980/3d-mapping-cliff-detection/) by [jacklu333333](https://answers.ros.org/users/68134/jacklu333333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2021-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your robot would have to move only on empty cells, and avoid unknown cells. The empty cells seem sparse in your screenshot, you may use [point_cloud_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap_ros.2Fpoint_cloud_assembler) node to accumulate multiple velodyne scans while moving and feed the `assembled_cloud` to rtabmap node instead of the velodyne point cloud. This could help to get denser empty cells in the static map. Parameter `Grid/MaxObstacleHeight` could be also set to -0.10 so that plane surfaces 10 cm under the ground are not labelled as empty, but obstacles instead.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1